# Firebase user display name causing crash

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running into a bug involving Firebase users displayName value. Here is my code:

```
if let user = user {
    if user.displayName == nil || user.displayName == "" {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddName", sender: nil)
    } else {
        let displayName = user.displayName!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
        if let fcmToken = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firToken") as? String {
            if !fcmToken.isEmpty {
        ref.child("cities").child(driversCurrentCity).child("loggedInDrivers").child(displayName).child("fcmToken").setValue(fcmToken)
        ref.child("cities").child(driversCurrentCity).child("loggedInDrivers").child("fcmTokens").child(fcmToken).setValue(true)
            ref.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("fcmToken").setValue(fcmToken)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "loginCompleted")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoggedInSuccess", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I use to set the displayName:

I'm using this function from Firebase to set the displayName:

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

For some users, everything works fine. However, some users experience a crash at the line

`ref.child("cities").child(driversCurrentCity).child("loggedInDrivers").child(displayName).child("fcmToken").setValue(fcmToken)`

I'm getting this error:
 Fatal Exception: InvalidPathValidation
(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'

I haven't been able to replicate it lately, but when I
 first started debugging the issue it was showing that displayName was some long string involving gestureRecognizer. It seems like some code when the sign in button is pressed is being applied to the displayName variable. I know this question is kind of vague but I appreciate any help!

Comment: Since you're not showing how `user.displayName` or `driversCurrentCity` get their values, it's going to be impossible to say what you've done wrong.

Comment: I'm using this function from Firebase to set the displayName:
`let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}`

Comment: Could you edit your question to show all the relevant code, so it's easy to read?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but from the error message it seems that either the display name or the city contains one of the disallowed characters (`.`, `#`, `$`, `[` or `]`). Given that the display name is whatever the user has entered, it can indeed contain disallowed characters and thus should be sanitized before using it as a key.